# What is the origin of the parmname: value syntax for passing paramters?

Tags: groovy, swift3, smalltalk

I learned groovy last summer and discovered the syntax for constructors that you can specify the parameter name with a value and initialize that value. For instance:

```
Team team = new Team(name: "Bengals")
```

At the end of the year, I upgraded IntelliJ and this syntax started showing up in my java functions with overloaded functions with different parameter lists. (This is not implemented very well. It's confusing when I try to change the values. I've figured it out, but poorly implemented.)

```
team.chant = (msg: "Who dey?");
```

Which is interesting, because I'm learning Swift 3 and it uses the same syntax.

It seems unlikely that Swift 3 was influenced by Groovy, so I'm curious. What language is putting pressure on these languages to support the parmname: value syntax?

It seems to me that Swift is based on what little I know about Smalltalk. Does Smalltalk support this parameter syntax?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter lists a number of languages that support named parameters: Ada, C# 4.0+, Ceylon, ColdFusion Markup Language (CFML), Common Lisp, Fortran, IDL, Kotlin, Mathematica, Objective-C, PL/SQL, Python, R, Ruby, Scala, Smalltalk, Swift, and Visual Basic.

Comment: examples here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Call_a_function and here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters

Comment: Interesting...newly added to C# too. Could see Objective-C feeding swift and C# both. Maybe that's the pressure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Swift nor Groovy, so I can only respond for the Smalltalk part.

Smalltalk does not support that syntax, but has keyword messages that read very much like that.

For instance,

```
team := Team new name: 'Bengals'.
team chant msg: 'who dey?'
```

is valid in Smalltalk.

It is not that the names of params are in the command, but the command itself is #name:, which matches the name of some instance variable but is a method to set its value... So as I said, it reads the same but the meaning is very different.